# WPF Relative Binding using hierarchical collection structure

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have an ObservableCollection containing an ObservableCollection:

```
public class BooksDetailModel
{
    public BookModel Book{ get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<AuthorModel> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

Property in ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<BooksDetailModel> Books { get; set; }
```

I would like to render this in a ListBox like this:

Book1

- Author1
- Author2

Book2

- Author1

etc.

The top level bind is easy but I am having trouble with the inner child collection.

XAML so far:

```
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Book.Name}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <ListBox>
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ???, Path=Author.Name}" FontSize="10" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Any suggestions for ??? - Relative binding the inner listbox itemsource to the parent itemsource's Authors collection.

Comment: You should be using a HierarchicalDataTemplate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should bind the `ItemsSource` of the inner `ListBox` to the `Authors` property. And the binding in the `DataTemplate` will be simply binding to the `Name` property of the author:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Book.Name}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Authors}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="10" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks - I am continually amazed by the flexibility of xaml binding.  I thought it might have something to do with RelativeSource.